# overloading case class constructor with implicit parameter?

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to define a case class with some params that have a default value, but the default value requires an implicit parameter. I've tried something like this:

```
case class ChannelLatches(started: TestLatch, stopped: TestLatch)(implicit system: ActorSystem) {
  def this()(implicit system: ActorSystem) = this(new TestLatch(), new TestLatch())(system)
}
```

and this:

```
case class ChannelLatches(started: TestLatch, stopped: TestLatch)(implicit system: ActorSystem) {
   def this()(implicit system: ActorSystem) = this(new TestLatch(), new TestLatch())(system)
}
```

but in both cases, the compiler does not recognize my new constructor.  Any pointers?

Comment: case class ChannelLatches(started: TestLatch = new TestLatch, stopped: TestLatch = new TestLatch)(implicit system: ActorSystem) {
}

Comment: This is what I tried originally, but the compiler generates an error like:  could not find implicit value for parameter system: akka.actor.ActorSystem.  I'm assuming because system is defined in a subsequent parameter list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not in the case class or its constructor. When you get compilation error like

```
scala> val channelLatches = new ChannelLatches
<console>:11: error: could not find implicit value for parameter system: ActorSystem
       val channelLatches = new ChannelLatches
                            ^
```

it means that you don't have an implicit variable of type ActorSystem available as a single identifier in the scope.

Both your code examples (they are exactly the same code, right?) and @Eastsun's example are perfectly legal code:

```
scala> class ActorSystem
defined class ActorSystem

scala> class TestLatch
defined class TestLatch

scala> case class ChannelLatches(started: TestLatch = new TestLatch, stopped: TestLatch = new TestLatch)(implicit system: ActorSystem)
defined class ChannelLatches

scala> implicit val actor = new ActorSystem
actor: ActorSystem = ActorSystem@586f403e

scala> val channelLatches = new ChannelLatches
channelLatches: ChannelLatches = ChannelLatches(TestLatch@521a74af,TestLatch@46e2b745)
```

Note the implicit val actor which makes it possible for the compiler to supply the missing parameter implicitly.

See [A Tour of Scala: Implicit Parameters](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/114) for introduction about implicit parameters.

--- Edit 2012-03-05: Added alternative example where ChannelLatches is inner class of Something

If you want ChannelLatches to be an inner class of something, you really don't need to pass the ActorSystem instance to the inner class instances as inner classes can access values from outer objects. [A Tour of Scala: Inner Classes](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/115)

```
scala> class ActorSystem
defined class ActorSystem

scala> class TestLatch
defined class TestLatch

scala> class Something(implicit val as: ActorSystem) {
     |   case class ChannelLatches(started: TestLatch, stopped: TestLatch) {
     |     def this() = this(new TestLatch(), new TestLatch())
     |  
     |     def actorSystem = as
     |   }
     | }
defined class Something

scala> implicit val as = new ActorSystem
as: ActorSystem = ActorSystem@5481be8a

scala> val s = new Something
s: Something = Something@7139acf

scala> val cl = new s.ChannelLatches
cl: s.ChannelLatches = ChannelLatches(TestLatch@38764254,TestLatch@5bfcb5c1)

scala> cl.actorSystem == as
res0: Boolean = true
```

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to have ChannelLatches to not be an inner class of something with an implicit system in scope.  That's why I was defining the implicit param on the case class (though, of course, that doesn't work in this context).  The ActorSystem needs to be provided by the caller.